# How to use PIPO SIPO Shift Register

Tags: shift-register

I had some questions regarding the 74299N shift register by Signetics before, but I have another one from Texas Instruments and I don't quite understand how to use it. (Here's the datasheet: https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/545779/TI/SN74199N.html)

Here is the pinout:

[image]

I connected it this way:

- SH/LD to 5V
- CLR to Ground
- CLK to Ground with a pull-down resistor and to 5V via a switch
- CLK INH to Ground
- K to 5V
- J to 5V

And all the outputs to LEDs connected to 5V (it has open collector outputs).

When I perform the low to high clock transition, nothing happens at all. The shift register is not overheating and seems to power on just fine.

Comment: A shift register like this was used for microcomputer input and output  in the era about 45 years ago when LSI MOS ICs cost a fortune. One could for ex. implement a control panel with numerous push buttons and LED indicator lamps which gets the states of the leds as serial data from the computer and sends the states of the buttons to the MC also as serial data. The leds were simply darkened during the short period when the shift register moved data. A short darkening is invisible.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. I will get my hands on some newer ones :)

Comment: Could I save the pulse with a latch?

Comment: If I continue what I have seen in retro devices I can add that the outputs of the shift registers were stored into a latch in case they must stay stable also when input data was taken into the shift register or shifts were done to move the data between the I/O apparatus and the MC. Such signals which didn't stand a short blanking were used to control external stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Grounding the CLR pin makes the chip to set outputs low and do nothing.

So it works as it should with that connection on CLR pin.

Comment: I tried it but it doesnt work either, I attached a link to the datasheet

Comment: Are you sure you input clean edged clock pulses. A switch+a resistor for pull-up is useless. You can make easily 10 shift pulses with one switch movement to ON and back to OFF. J, K and SH/LD must all be set differently for different operation phases as the datasheet shows.